# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error

Tags: java

I'm beginning to learn Java. While following a YouTube tutorial, I entered the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ageclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age;
        System.out.println("How older are you?");
        age=in.nextInt();
        if (age >= 18)
            System.out.println("you are old enough to drink");
        else
            System.out.println("you are not old enough");
    }
}
```

The code threw this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at age.ageclass.main(ageclass.java:6)
```

I have looked at another thread that had an answer but I couldn't understand it. Could someone explain to me what has gone wrong?

Comment: What does the tutorial say? Go review the actual source code.

Comment: did you actually try to compile?

Comment: Could you post a link to the YouTube tutorial? And post a link to the other thread which had the answer you could not understand? Through which methods are you trying to compile and execute the code (i.e., command-line, IDE like Eclipse, etc)?

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis the tutorial doesn't say anything about the error, I read the comments and no one seemed to have this problem (or well didn't post a comment about it) here is the URL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cfd9DOnuF9w

@Dan I am using Eclipse, I was under the impression it complies it on the fly? EDIT : here is a link to the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688858/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-error

Comment: I think in Eclipse you have to tell it to compile before running. I believe that's under the Build menu? But I remember this from over 5 years ago and it may have changed.

Comment: First of all, you should learn using reliable sources of information, like a good book, or the official Java tutorial at Oracle. Learning from a Youtube tutorial that doesn't even indent the code properly and respect the Java naming conventions is not a good idea. And you're using Eclipse. Make sure to always have the "Problems" view opened (Window - Show View...), and to not even try to maunch your program while there are errors listed in this view. Read the error messages, and fix the errors. Running non-compilable code is nonsense. Eclipse warned you about it, but you ignored the warning.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks the problem view told me what was wrong, I must of deleted package age; my bad, would you recommend me some books please this might not of happened if I had reputable sources

Comment: I learnt Java 17 years ago :-) It's been a long time I haven't cared about introductory Java books. AFAIK, Thinking in Java is a good one: http://mindview.net/Books/TIJ4

Comment: I will have a look at it, thank you for your help =]

Answer (score 2):

if you are using eclipse try to clean the project.

Project -> Clean... -> select your project -> OK

Comment: The user appears to be a novice at Java. Can you explain to them why this might help?

Comment: I did this and it still comes back with the error, but I am intrested in why this would help (for future reference)

Comment: When you clean your project, eclipse remove the artifacts of your project.

plus... if you have the auto-build turned on, eclipse will compile your project again.